# Saving Image to Directory gets Tilted to some angle

Tags: android, image-processing

I'm capturing Image from Camera in android and then saving the image to the external directory but its getting tilt to some angle as shown in attached image. Please suggest I've no idea why this is happening. I'm testing on my device as well but the issue is not reproducing. However my client has raised this issue. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();

Camera.getCameraInfo(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, info);

int rotation = mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
int degrees = 0;

switch (rotation) {

```
case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break; //Natural orientation
    case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break; //Landscape left
    case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;//Upside down
    case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;//Landscape right
}
```

int rotate = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;

Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

params.setRotation(rotate);

mCamera.setParameters(params);

Your solution is kind of a workaround since you modify the image AFTER it was already recorded. This solution is cleaner and doesn't require all these 'if' statements before saving the image.

Comment: But this is not a 90 degree or multiple of 90 degree rotation. I'm aware of such rotation because of orientation but this is unexpected to me. Well I'll try this. thanks for replying.